# Sculpting for animation caveats?

Tags: animation, scripting

I know to sculpt my characters with an A-Pose or T-Pose to save myself a lot of headaches later.  As well as toes that point forward and straight fingers and a little bend on knees and elbows.

What I'm concerned about are the eyelids and lips.  Since eyelids open and close, would I need more geometry around the eyes? How would I even do that? During retopology phase?  Should I sculpt with the eyes closed?  Same with lips, would it deform strange of the mouth is too small?  How would I even know before hand?

Is there a general rule book for sculpting for animation?  Pitfalls that people don't discover until they start animating?

Comment: Sculpt the face in a neutral expression. Might be good to make the mouth only slightly open and the eyelids only slightly closed. It's after sculpting, when you're doing retopology, that you should make sure to add enough edge loops around the mouth and eyes so that the rigger has enough geometry to create the deformations needed.

Comment: I see.  That's a good idea, I didn't think of doing it "half way".  I guess open eyes is impossible for eye lids?  Since its all folded up, you'll have geometry on top of each other.  Do you think sculpting with eyes closed is a better option? I'll only need to worry about deformations in that case.